# In group by elements, select value different from null in other column

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I have a list:

```
| Student    |       Sport |           
|------------|-------------|    
| AA         |             |        
| AA         |   Football  |           
| BB         |   Basketball|         
| BB         |             |
```

I want to group by name and show the value in sport that is different from null or empty.

so far I got the idea

```
var result = from elements in studenList
               group elements by elements.name into grouped
               select new student {
                 name = grouped.First().name,
                 sport = // HOW I GET THIS PART??
               };
```

I tried something like:

```
sport =  string.Join(" ", (grouped.Select(x => x.sport).Distinct().ToArray()))
```

but it adds many spaces between the sport names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there, just add a filter to remove the null and empty entries:

```
sport =  string.Join(
    " ", 
    grouped.Select(x => x.sport)
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
        .Distinct())
```